# Android Studio TODO list does not refresh

Tags: android, android-studio, todo

How can I refresh TODO list in the Android Studio? The list gets stuck and displays items that I have already removed and saved in files. I checked Stackoverflow and other places and could not find this.

Two tabs in the TODO (Project vs Current) show conflicting things:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the support pages of Android Studio or IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3):

Try closing the project and opening again, maybe closing some other projects if you have many.

I had a few projects open, others were refreshing ok, so I closed them (all but one older) and when I opened again the problematic one, now it's refreshing ok. Puzzled, I tried to recreate the problem by opening 6 AS projects, but this time all are behaving ok.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio:
1. Build->Clean Project
2. Build->Make Project